# Xcode4 Create Static Library from Existing Project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, static-libraries

Having trouble creating a static library in XCode4. I have been following this helpful [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/):

But I keep running into the same problem. How do you create a library from an existing project? I'm having difficulty building the project (not running) because it seems to run into compiler errors within the code I just imported.

How do I set up an existing project for importing into a Cocoa Touch Static Library project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select 
    **Target-> Build Settings** 
In the Linking Section Change the **Mach-O Type** to **Static Library**

[image]

You Can Try [this](http://muthukumarela.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/ios-static-libraries-without-adding-header-files/) for making your static library usage smart

Comment: Curious, when I open an existing project and do just above (not the link) I get a compiler error as such; are the steps in the link necessary?:

`Check dependencies

Application target has invalid MACH_O_TYPE value of 'staticlib'.`

Comment: Steps in the links are not necessary. But you have to add all static Library header files into the project then only you can use the static  library inside you project. An alternative is way is prescribed in that link