# It is not calling NSObject Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I created simple NSObject class to take some values. My application has not come any error when I run and build the application. I tried it lot of time to run program. I am beginner of the objective c.

Code ::

```
#import "FibonachiNo.h"

@implementation FibonachiNo

- (NSArray *) fibonacci:(NSInteger) n {

    NSMutableArray *fib = [NSMutableArray array];

    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int sum;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        [fib addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a]];
        sum = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = sum;
    }

    return (NSArray *) fib;
}

- (NSInteger) factorial:(NSInteger) n {
    if ( n <= 1 )
        return 1;
    else
        return n * [self factorial:( n-1 )];
}

@end
```

My application header class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FibonachiNo.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property FibonachiNo *myFibonachi;
@end
```

Calling Method to NSObject Class ::

```
  NSLog(@"fibonacci for 10 = %@", [myFibonachi fibonacci:10]);
  NSLog(@"10! = %d",[myFibonachi factorial:10]);
```

Is it any wrong in this calling method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first alloc init your Array

```
#import "FibonachiNo.h"

@implementation FibonachiNo

- (NSArray *) fibonacci:(NSInteger) n {

    NSMutableArray *fib = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int sum;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        [fib addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a]];
        sum = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = sum;
    }

    return fib;
}

- (NSInteger) factorial:(NSInteger) n {
    if ( n <= 1 )
        return 1;
    else
        return n * [self factorial:( n-1 )];
}

@end
```

Calling Method to NSObject Class ::

in `ViewDidLoad` use following.

```
FibonachiNo *myFibonachi=[[FibonachiNo alloc]init];
  NSLog(@"fibonacci for 10 = %@", [myFibonachi fibonacci:10]);
  NSLog(@"10! = %d",[myFibonachi factorial:10]);
```

if still you facing any issue , then show your NSLog output here.

Comment: Now it's running properly.I have another problem. I create this class in static class library. and I did changes in Mach-O Type to Static Library and added abc.a and abc.h files to my new application. then show bellow error Check dependencies

Application target has invalid MACH_O_TYPE value of 'staticlib'.:

Comment: Opens up the project.pbxproj file in YourProjectName.xcodeproj folder using TextEdit, search for productType and change it's value from "com.apple.product-dynamic" to "com.apple.product-static"

Comment: Also you can try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255044/xcode4-create-static-library-from-existing-project

Answer (score 0):

try using

@synthesize *myFibonachi;

in your ViewController.m file below @implementation