# Xcode8.2 create a static library from an existing iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I have a fully functional iOS project (objective-c) that uses different cocoapods libraries, storyboard, DBManager files and all the files that a normal app can have. However we need to share our project/app with one of the client, and I am thinking to share it as a static library.

My question is How can I convert a current existing project into a static universal library and is it even possible to do so, I looked into this, however all I could find is guide on creating a brand new static library.

There are few similar stack overflow questions I came across like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255044/xcode4-create-static-library-from-existing-project) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624604/how-to-create-a-static-library-from-an-xcode-project) but solutions are little vague or for me its hard to follow

Any help on this would be appreciable

Thanks